# How do I calculate a monthly rate of change from a daily time series in R?

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I'm beginning to get my feet wet with R, and I'm brand new to time series concepts. Can anyone point me in the right direction to calculate a monthly % change, based on a daily data point? I want the change between the first and last data points of each month. For example:

tseries data:

```
1/1/2000 10.00
...
1/31/2000 10.10
2/1/2000 10.20
...
2/28/2000 11.00
```

I'm looking for a return data frame of the form:

```
1/31/2000 .01
2/28/2000 .0784
```

Ideally, I'd be able to calculate from the endpoint of the prior month to the endpoint of current month, but I'm supposing partitioning by month is easier as a starting point. I'm looking at packages zoo and xts, but am still stuck. Any takers? Thanks...

Comment: What have you tried? Did you skim the zoo and xts vignettes for an answer? Have you searched the [xts] tag?

Comment: am parsing them now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using `plyr` and `ddply`. 
I use ddply sequentially, first to get the first and last rows of each month, and again to calculate the **monthlyReturn.**
(Perhaps using xts or zoo might be easier, I am not sure.)

```
#Using plyr and the data in df
df$Date <- as.POSIXlt(as.Date(df$Date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
df$Month <- (df$Date$mon + 1) #0 = January

sdf <- df[,-1] #drop the Date Column, ddply doesn't like it

library("plyr")
#this function is called with 2 row data frames
monthlyReturn<- function(df) {
  (df$Value[2] - df$Value[1])/(df$Value[1])  
}

adf <- ddply(sdf, .(Month), function(x) x[c(1, nrow(x)), ]) #get first and last values for each Month   
mon.returns <- ddply(adf, .(Month), monthlyReturn)
```

Here's the data I used to test it out:

```
> df
         Date Value
1    1/1/2000  10.0
2   1/31/2000  10.1
3    2/1/2000  10.2
4   2/28/2000  11.0
5    3/1/2000  10.0
6   3/31/2000  24.1
7   5/10/2000 510.0
8   5/22/2000 522.0
9   6/04/2000 604.0
10  7/03/2000  10.1
11  7/30/2000   7.2
12 12/28/2000  11.0
13 12/30/2000   3.0

> mon.returns
  Month          V1
1     1  0.01000000
2     2  0.07843137
3     3  1.41000000
4     5  0.02352941
5     6  0.00000000
6     7 -0.28712871
7    12 -0.72727273
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ram, thank you. Zoo and xts were the way to go, but this got me started in thinking about the structure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do this(using the quantmod package):

This calculates the monthly return from the daily price of AAPL.

```
*library(quantmod)     # load the quantmod package
getSymbols("AAPL")     # download daily price for stock AAPL
monthlyReturn = periodReturn(AAPL,period="monthly")
monthlyReturn2014 = periodReturn(AAPL,period="monthly",subset='2014:') # for 2014*
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old thread, but for reference, here comes a `data.table` solution using same data as @Ram:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(10957, 10987, 10988, 11015, 11017, 11047, 11087, 11099, 11112, 11141, 11168, 11319, 11321), class = "Date"), Value = c(10, 10.1, 10.2, 11, 10, 24.1, 510, 522, 604, 10.1, 7.2, 11, 3)), .Names = c("Date", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000001b0788>)
```

It's essentially a one-liner that uses the `data.table::month` function:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[ , diff(Value) / Value[1], by= .(month(Date))]
```

This will produce the change, relative to the first recorded day in each month. If the change relative to the **last** day is preferred, then the expression in the middle should be changed to `diff(Value) / Vale[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

**1) no packages** Try this:

```
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)

fmt <- "%m/%d/%Y"
ym <- format(as.Date(DF$V1, format = fmt), "%Y-%m")

ret <- function(x) diff(range(x))/x[1]
ag <- aggregate(V2 ~ ym, DF, ret)
```

giving:

```
> ag
       ym         V2
1 2000-01 0.01000000
2 2000-02 0.07843137
```

We could convert this to `"ts"` class, if desired. Assuming no missing months:

```
ts(ag$V2, start = 2000, freq = 12)
```

giving:

```
            Jan        Feb
2000 0.01000000 0.07843137
```

**2)** It's a bit easier if you use the zoo or xts time series packages.  `fmt` and `ret` are from above:

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, format = fmt)
z.ret <- aggregate(z, as.yearmon, ret)
```

giving:

```
> z.ret
  Jan 2000   Feb 2000 
0.01000000 0.07843137
```

If you already have a data.frame `DF` then the `read.zoo` statement could be replaced with `z <- read.zoo(DF, format = fmt)` or omit the `format` arg if the first column is of `"Date"` class.

If `"ts"` class were desired then use `as.ts(z.ret)`

**Note:** The input `Lines` is:

```
Lines <- "1/1/2000 10.00
1/31/2000 10.10
2/1/2000 10.20
2/28/2000 11.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

The ROC function in the TTR package will do this. You can use to.monthly or endpoints() ([From daily time series to weekly time series in R xts object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402915/from-daily-time-series-to-weekly-time-series-in-r-xts-object?lq=1)) first if you will only be looking at monthly behaviour.

```
library(TTR)
# data.monthly <- to.monthly( data, indexAt='periodEnd' ) # if OHLC data
# OR
data.monthly <- data[ endpoints(data, on="months", k=1), ]
data.roc <- ROC(data.monthly, n = 1, type = "discrete")
```